# Hot code replacement in erlang

Tags: erlang

I am working on my first real project in erlang, however, this code is simplified for brevity.  I want to be able to load a newer version of a file into my project **remotely** while it's running.  I've read about using a behavior like `gen_server` or `gen_fsm` which has this for free.  While that might achieve the result, I want to use this to learn how to do it, not just get it done.  I've read the docs about [code replacement](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/code_loading.html#id83918), and LYSE's bit about [Hot Code Loving](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/designing-a-concurrent-application#hot-code-loving), among other things, but I haven't been able to find anything that works for what I'm doing, so here is the basic idea.

```
-module(reloading).

-export([loop/0]).

loop() ->
    receive
        upgrade ->
            ?MODULE:loop();
        hello ->
            io:format("This is a test~n"),
            loop();
        _ ->
            loop()
    end.
```

I am simply looping with the idea that I can send the message `upgrade` and it will load a newer version of the code.

```
$ erl
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> c(reloading).
{ok,reloading}
2> Loop = spawn(reloading, loop, []).
<0.39.0>
3> Loop ! hello.
This is a test
hello
```

At this point I change 10 line to `io:format("I have changed this!~n"),`

```
4> Loop ! upgrade.
upgrade
5> Loop ! hello.  
This is a test
hello
```

I am expecting this `hello` call to print `I have changed this!` not `This is a test`.  I know I can simply call `c(reloading).` and have this work the way expected, but I'm looking to send the actual project a message rather than manually updating the code.  So where is my disconnect?  What am I doing wrong, that I should be doing in order to hot load this code?  As mentioned before, I am looking for a non-OTP solution for the sake of education.

Comment: In shell: `c(reloading), l(reloading).`

Comment: @MuzaayaJoshua as I mentioned in my last paragraph, I know I can use `c(reloading).`, but in the actual project I don't want to use `erl`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For the sake of having an explicit answer, I am posting this.

Using `@rvirding`'s suggestion of using the [code](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html) module, I've modified it to look like this:

```
-module(reloading).

-export([loop/0]).

loop() ->
    receive
        upgrade ->
            code:purge(?MODULE),
            compile:file(?MODULE),
            code:load_file(?MODULE),
            ?MODULE:loop();
        hello ->
            io:format("This is a test~n"),
            loop();
        _ ->
            loop()
    end.
```

First [code:purge](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#purge-1) the old `?MODULE`, then [compile:file](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html#file-1) the new file, and finally, [code:load_file](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#load_file-1) the new `?MODULE`.
This works as I originally intended.

```
$ erl
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> Loop = spawn(reloading, loop, []).
<0.34.0>
2> Loop ! hello.
This is a test
hello
```

Change line to `io:format("I have changed this!~n"),`

```
3> Loop ! upgrade.                   
upgrade
4> Loop ! hello.  
I have changed this!
hello
```

Comment: Generally this explicit handling of the new module (compile,purge,load) is not done in the actual server. You have an environment around which handles the code and then when the new version has been loaded you send the `upgrade` message to the server. This is also the only way if you have many servers which use the same code. OTP works like this.

Answer (score 19):

While erlang can handle two versions of a module and calling a function with `mod:func(...)` will always call the latest version of a module (if the function is exported) you still have to load the new version of the module into Erlang system. You can't expect it automagically detect that you happen to have a new version of the module somewhere, find it, compile it and load it.

**N.B.** compiling and loading are two separate things. So `c(mod).` **both** compiles **and** loads the module, while `l(mod).` just loads the object code (.beam file) of the already compiled module. The Erlang compiler is called from the module `compile` and it just compiles and generates a .beam file while the code loading is handled by the module `code`.

Comment: Okay, cool, that makes sense. So how do I load the new version of the module without using the shell?

Comment: @joneshf It's all done through the module `code` with `code:load_file(Mod)`. This is what both `c/1` and `l/1` in the shell use. For more docs see http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above I'd like to notice that some tools that reload code automatically for you exist.

You should have a look at [sync](https://github.com/rustyio/sync) or [active](https://github.com/synrc/active) projects.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of those projects. Without sounding snarky/ungrateful, this doesn't really provide answers to the questions posed. This answer might make more sense as a comment.

Comment: @joneshf, I know, but I'm afraid it will not get enough attention as a comment while actually people searching for (automatic) hot code replacement will be more satisfied with those project than hand made solutions

Comment: Then maybe the problem is the title of the question is not specific enough. It could be changed to "Manual hot code replacement in Erlang", or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Compile *.beam locally, then send it to your server and reload it as mentioned in man pages:

http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-1/reference_manual/code_loading.html#id86381

```
-module(m).
-export([loop/0]).

loop() ->
    receive
        code_switch ->
            m:loop();
        Msg ->
            ...
            loop()
    end.
```